Overwrite strip language processor for sxa sites only
I have Multiple sites in one instance sxa and non sxa sites.
I want to Overwrite strip language processor for sxa sites only.
How to achieve this.

You can add below check inside the custom processor created for StripLanguage, inside the preprocessRequest pipeline to check for SXA site.
public class CustomStripLanguage : StripLanguage
{
  public override void Process(PreprocessRequestArgs args)
  {
    var hostName = args.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host;
    SiteInfo site = SiteContextFactory.Sites
                       .Where(s => s.RootPath != "" & s.HostName.Contains(hostName))
                       .FirstOrDefault();
    if (site != null)
    {
       SiteContext contextSite = SiteContextFactory.GetSiteContext(site.Name);
       if (contextSite.IsSxaSite())
       {
          // custom code to overwrite strip language.
       }
     }
  }
}

In the above class, OOTB IsSxaSite helper function is used to decide whether the current site context is SXA site.
You can patch above configuration as below.
 <configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
     <pipelines>
       <preprocessRequest>
         <processor type="YourNamespace.CustomStripLanguage, YourAssemblyName" patch:instead="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.PreprocessRequest.StripLanguage, Sitecore.Kernel']" />
       </preprocessRequest>
     </pipelines>
   </sitecore>
 </configuration>

Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you face any issues.
